# Azure Resources not visible in VS Code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, vscode-extensions

I am using VS Code to authenticate Azure Account and Create and deploy function apps via VS Code. I have some subscription in my account.

But, recently when I tried to deploy the resources the Azure Extension was unable to find the subscription and its related resources.

Details about Configuration:
**Vscode version: 1.84.2
Azure Resource Extension version: v0.8.0**

[image: Extension Image]

Here is details about the Azure Resource Extensions.

[image: Azure Resource Group]

Here it says to Select Subscription ID: But No Subscription id is visible to select.
[image: No Subscription ID is Visible]

I tried to uninstall the Azure Extension and VS Code several time, but the issue remained same. I logout from Azure and tried to setup new account in it but the issue remained same.

Any one know these odd behavior's from VS Code or Azure Extension.

Comment: have you try to log in again ? you creds may have expired

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I have tried multiple logins, and with same credentials I am able to access the Portal, the Credentials not expired. As the login for Azure Extension is successful everytime.

Comment: "What error you are getting?"  The Resource Groups and Subscription is not visible so I am unable to select on which function app i need deploy the changes

Comment: @RoronoaZoro, can you click on the Azure icon in the left pane of VSCode and share the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/S0VoHlN.png) of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed, yet it's a temporary solution.

According to this document, version 0.8.0 contains a minor issue that has been addressed.

After reverting the Azure Resource version to 0.7.1, the problem was temporarily fixed. However, upon upgrading to version 0.8.0, the issue persisted, and I couldn't view the Azure resources.

Github Issue: [Azure Resource Group Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3907#issuecomment-1823794290) || [Azure Resource Group Issue 2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureresourcegroups/issues/769#issuecomment-1821422662)

According to the GitHub issues, it has been indicated that the resolution for this problem will be implemented in the forthcoming version update.

I am adding the artifact regarding the Azure Resource Group.

- Previous Version of Azure Resource Group:

[image: Previous Version]

- Downgraded Version of Azure Resource:

[image: Downgraded Azure Resource Version]

- Subscription is Visible:

[image: Subscription is Visible]

Comment: Hello @Pravallika KV If you have anything to add please let me know

Comment: Glad that your issue got resolved. And in Azure Resource version 0.8.0, by removing `TenantId` in `settings(or) settings.json` in vscode and signin again `Azure: Signin`.

Answer (score 0):

**After installing Azure Extensions:**

- Navigate to **Azure icon** in the left pane of the Visual Studio Code.
- Click on the `...`(Views and More Actions) in the Top:

  - Check if the resources and workspaces option is selected or not.
  - If not selected, you won't be able to see the subscriptions and all other resources.

[image]

- Select both **resources** and **workspaces**.

[image]

Comment: Hii I have updated the Question with the required screenshot.

Comment: How did you signin to Azure in VSCode? Try to signin using command palette(ctrl+shift+p)=>search for `Azure Sign in`  and sign in with your credentials?

Comment: Yes I have used Command Palette to Sign In, I have performed this action multiple times.

Comment: Search for `Azure: Select Tenant` in command palette and let me know if you are able to see the TenantId.

Comment: Yes the tenant, is visible.

Comment: Select the Tenant and it'll re-prompt you to signin again. Refer [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/wiki/Troubleshooting#unable-to-list-subscriptions)

Comment: I selected the Tennant ID, and Login to Azure Account Again, But the issue remained Same

Comment: What are the options you have if you search for `Azure: Select Subscriptions` in command palette?

Comment: Its Shows all my subscription, but when I Select them it not selected. I fells like it is stuck. and When Click on Selecting Subscription from Azure Resource then it returns empty field.

Comment: Login to `portal.azure.com` in browser and then try signin in vscode. If this doesn't work clear cache in your system and try these steps again.

Comment: Thank you for the steps, the issue is temporarily solved. I will update the answer here in answer section soon. With the steps I took.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow the [Azure Resources documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureresourcegroups)

There you can search for the section **"How to Sign In"**. If it happends as happends to me, you would not see the `Sign in to Azure...` option on the **"RESOURSES"** section. This is beacuse you are authenticated with you vscode user, what's it's a new functionality they add. You should use the new "**Azure: Sign In**" command

[image]